# Space between buttons with bootstrap class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with three buttons on my site.
I would like to have some space between those buttons.
Is it possible to do this, without using inline styling? 
Perhaps bootstrap has some classes for this?

I know I can simply do it with:

```
style='margin-right:5px;'
```

or write custom class with this property.

I am just wondering if bootstrap has some classes for this?

[Here](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/oZPRoK?editors=1000) is example.

Problem is with this three buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes you have to wrap them**

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1/2</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1/2</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">1/2</button>
</div>
```

[EDITED CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sandwell/pen/LWJKMy?editors=1000)

Comment: Is it possible to increase / decrease this spacing?

Comment: Yes by overridding bootstrap class. You add a specific class and use margin: 0 10px

Answer (score 4):

Try to put them inside btn-toolbar or some other container.

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-1">1/2</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d-flex justify-content-between

<div class="col-md-3 mt-4 d-flex justify-content-betweend-flex justify-content-between">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-light" id="atndanceFilter"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Filter Report</button>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary">Reset</a>
</div>
```

Will work like magic.