# Bootstrap button space between

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, space

how does one add space between button in bootstrap

[image: button with spacing]

this is how my buttons come our as per there code base

[image: button with no spacing]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space between buttons with bootstrap class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065802/space-between-buttons-with-bootstrap-class)

Answer (score 0):

try to user `&nbsp;` between button...
Here is the example https://codepen.io/acakluqman/pen/NYLNjj